# How to filter rows alphabetically by groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with **items that belongs to a document issue**. For example, doc1 issue A has items 1 and 2; doc1 issue B has items 5 and 8.

```
df_source=pd.DataFrame([('doc1','A',1,4),('doc1','A',2,0),('doc1','B',5,6),('doc1','B',8,6), ('doc1','C',8,4),('doc1','C',4,4), ('doc2','B',0,5),('doc2','B',1,5), ('doc3','B',5,6),('doc3','K',4,4),('doc3','K',10,4)], columns=['Doc_name','Doc_Issue','item','prop2'])

   Doc_name Doc_Issue  item  prop2
0      doc1         A     1      4
1      doc1         A     2      0
2      doc1         B     5      6
3      doc1         B     8      6
4      doc1         C     8      4
5      doc1         C     4      4
6      doc2         B     0      5
7      doc2         B     1      5
8      doc3         B     5      6
9      doc3         K     4      4
10     doc3         K    10      4
```

I would like to filter the DataFrame so I get only the items at all latest issue:

```
df_result=pd.DataFrame([('doc1','C',8,4),('doc1','C',4,4), ('doc2','B',0,5),('doc2','B',1,5), ('doc3','K',4,4),('doc3','K',10,4)], columns=['Doc_name','Doc_Issue','item','prop2'])

  Doc_name Doc_Issue  item  prop2
0     doc1         C     8      4
1     doc1         C     4      4
2     doc2         B     0      5
3     doc2         B     1      5
4     doc3         K     4      4
5     doc3         K    10      4
```

Comment: Please define the "latest issue". It seems to be alphabetical, but it's not fully clear. And what about lower- and uppercase letters for the issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case do `transform` + `last`

```
out = df[df.Doc_Issue ==df.groupby('Doc_name')['Doc_Issue'].transform('last')]
Out[60]: 
   Doc_name Doc_Issue  item  prop2
4      doc1         C     8      4
5      doc1         C     4      4
6      doc2         B     0      5
7      doc2         B     1      5
9      doc3         K     4      4
10     doc3         K    10      4
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the last two in each group and filter them using the loc accessor. Pass the index values to use the loc accccesor. Code below

```
 df_source.loc[df_source.groupby('Doc_name')['Doc_Issue'].tail(2).index.get_level_values(0),:]



  Doc_name Doc_Issue  item  prop2
4      doc1         C     8      4
5      doc1         C     4      4
6      doc2         B     0      5
7      doc2         B     1      5
9      doc3         K     4      4
10     doc3         K    10      4
```